# Having trouble with moving information

Tags: c#

I seem to of hit a bit of a snag in a program I am trying to make for school. I am suppose to make a new class to receive data and get a total to send to a new screen. Well I did the same thing we did in class, but the difference is that that was from a text box and there is no text box for the data I need to move this time, so the way I tried gave me an error. Here is what I got so far:

```
    public StudentSelection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public decimal firstCounter;
    public decimal secondCounter;
    public decimal finalCounter;

    struct StudentScores
    {
        public string StuId;
        public decimal TestOne;
        public decimal TestTwo;
        public decimal Final;  
    }
    StudentScores[] allStudentScores = new StudentScores[10]; 
    // class level array to hold 10 products - read in from a file

    private void StudentSelection_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // read products file into products structure array
        try
        {


            // ALWAYS initialize a structure array before using the array
            //  before adding, changing, etc.
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                allStudentScores[x].StuId = "";
                allStudentScores[x].TestOne = 0;
                allStudentScores[x].TestTwo = 0;
                allStudentScores[x].Final = 0;
            }

            int arrayIndex = 0; // needed for incrementing index value of the array
            // when reading file into array

            // now read file into the array after initialization
            StreamReader inputFile;

            string lineofdata; // used to hold each line of data read in from the file
            string[] ProductStringArray = new string[4]; // 6 element string array to hold 
            // each "field" read from every line in file

            inputFile = File.OpenText("StudentScores.txt"); // open for reading

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream) //keep reading until end of file
            {
                lineofdata = inputFile.ReadLine(); // ReadLine() reads an entire row of data from file
                ProductStringArray = lineofdata.Split(','); //each field is separated by ';'
                allStudentScores[arrayIndex].StuId = ProductStringArray[0]; // add first element of array to first column of allProducts
                allStudentScores[arrayIndex].TestOne = decimal.Parse(ProductStringArray[1]);
                firstCounter += allStudentScores[arrayIndex].TestOne;
                allStudentScores[arrayIndex].TestTwo = decimal.Parse(ProductStringArray[2]);
                secondCounter += allStudentScores[arrayIndex].TestTwo;
                allStudentScores[arrayIndex].Final = decimal.Parse(ProductStringArray[3]);
                finalCounter += allStudentScores[arrayIndex].Final;
                StudentListView.Items.Add(ProductStringArray[0]);
                arrayIndex++; // increment so NEXT row is updated with next read

            }

            //close the file
            inputFile.Close(); 
        }
        catch (Exception anError)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(anError.Message);

        }
    }
    private void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal firstResult, secondResult, finalResult, stuOne, stuTwo, stuThree;
        string stuName;

        // call the method in our datatier class
        decimal.TryParse(firstCounter, out firstResult);
        decimal.TryParse(secondCounter, out secondResult);
        decimal.TryParse(finalCounter, out finalResult);

        DataTier.AddOurNumbers(firstResult, secondResult, finalResult);
        DataTier.StudentData(stuName, stuOne, stuTwo, stuThree);

        // now hide this window and display a third window with the total
        this.Hide();
        // display third window
        ScoreScreen aScoreScreen = new ScoreScreen();
        aScoreScreen.Show();
    }


}
```

and my new class

```
class DataTier
{
    // public static variable available to all windows
    public static decimal firstTotal, secondTotal, finalTotal, stuTestOne, stuTestTwo, stuTestThree;
    // static is not associated with any object

    public static string stuIDCode;

    // create a public method to access from all windows
    public static void AddOurNumbers(decimal NumOne, decimal NumTwo, decimal numThree)
    {
        // devide to get an average
        firstTotal = NumOne / 10;
        secondTotal = NumTwo / 10;
        finalTotal = numThree / 10;
    }

    public static void StudentData(string name, decimal testOne, decimal testTwo, decimal testThree)
    {
        stuIDCode = name;
        stuTestOne = testOne;
        stuTestTwo = testTwo;
        stuTestThree = testThree;
    }
}
```

The error is at the three decimal.TryParse parts and I have no clue why it is not working except the error says "cannot convert from decimal to string". Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it from:

```
    decimal.TryParse(firstCounter, out firstResult);
    decimal.TryParse(secondCounter, out secondResult);
    decimal.TryParse(finalCounter, out finalResult);

    DataTier.AddOurNumbers(firstResult, secondResult, finalResult);
```

To:

```
    DataTier.AddOurNumbers(firstCounter, secondCounter, finalCounter);
```

The problem is that you're trying to call [`decimal.TryParse(string s, out decimal result)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) as decimal.TryParse(decimal s, out decimal result).

Your input is already `decimal` and doesn't require any conversion.

---

As a side note is that the code

```
 decimal.TryParse(someString, out someOutputDecimal);
```

without a proper *if statement* around it will fail silently (it doesn't inform anything about the failure). In fact the output value is set to 0, and it acts as if no faulty input was received. If the input should always be valid, you should use [`decimal.Parse(someString)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx) instead. However in some cases defaulting to 0 if the input is invalid, can be the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `decimal.TryParse()` method takes a string as its first argument and attempts to convert it to a `decimal` value.  In your case, the variables you are passing to `TryParse()` are already `decimal` variables and there is no need to parse them.  If you want to just copy class variables to local variables, all you need to do is this:

```
firstResult = firstCounter;
secondResult = secondCounter;
finalResult = finalCounter;
```

Or in this particular case, you can just pass the class variables directly into `AddOurNumbers`:

```
DataTier.AddOurNumbers(firstCounter, secondCounter, finalCounter);
```

One thing to note here is that value types, such as `decimals` and other primitives in C# get copied any time you assign them from one value to another, or pass them into a method.  This means that even if the value of `firstCounter`, `secondCounter`, or `thirdCounter` changes after calling `DataTier.AddOurNumbers()`, the values that your data tier has already recieved will not change.

Comment: Their immutability doesn't have to do with the reason why they're being copied. They're being copied because they are [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). Even a mutable struct (which is strongly recommended against) will be copied when assigned to a different variable. The result differs almost identical as adding a mutable reference type in a value type. But C# primitives are special cases of value types that are treated differently from most. However the information here is irrelevant to the problem in this question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I don't think their being value types is necessarily irrelevant here, because I suspect the asker was using `TryParse()` in an attempt to make copies of these variables.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Quote the question "*Well I did the same thing we did in class, but the difference is that that was from a text box and there is no text box for the data I need to move this time*". So he isn't trying to copy them, he just used code from his class, which used a `TextBox` (and therefore a `string`) as input. He just tried to convert `decimal` to `decimal`, which is redundant and due to function signatures results in an error.

Comment: Ok, you're probably right, but I did indeed point out in the first half of my post why the `TryParse()` is redundant.